# Huffman Encoder, trying to pass a string from a txt file with no luck. <3 lines needed

Tags: java

I have a file named "EE.txt" that contains the string: "E R R O R". As you can see in the compiler notes I have posted, I'm trying to call Huffman Tree and pass EE.txt along with it, for the filename. Anyone have any suggestions?

HuffmanNode.java

```
public class HuffmanNode implements Comparable
{
    public String letter;
    public Double frequency;
    public HuffmanNode left, right;

    // - add constructors to initialize letter and frequency, etc.
    public HuffmanNode(String letter, Double frequency)
    {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.frequency = frequency;
    }

    public HuffmanNode(String letter, Double frequency)
    {
        Double freq = Double.parseDouble( frequency );
        this.letter = letter;
        this.frequency = freq;
    }

    public HuffmanNode(HuffmanNode left, HuffmanNode right)
    {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
        this.letter = left.letter + right.letter;
        this.frequency = left.frequency + right.frequency;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "<" + this.letter + ", " + this.frequency + ">";
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
        HuffmanNode huff = (HuffmanNode) o;
        return this.frequency.compareTo( huff.frequency );
    }
}
```

HuffmanTree

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HuffmanTree {

    HuffmanNode root;

    // - add a constructor to init the Tree from a HuffmanNode
    public HuffmanTree(HuffmanNode huff)
    {
        this.root = huff;
    }

    // print legend
    public void printLegend()
    {
        this.printLegend(this.root, "");
    }

    private void printLegend(HuffmanNode t, String s)
    {
        if( t.letter.length() > 1 )
        {
            this.printLegend( t.left, s + "0");
            this.printLegend( t.right, s + "1" );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print( t.letter + "=" + s );
        }
    }

    // takes a String for the file name containing our input (letter & frequency data).
    // The letters and frequencies are all in the first line of the file, with spaces as separators.
    // (You may assume each separator is a single space).
    public static BinaryHeap fileToHeap(String filename)
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( filename ));

            String line = br.readLine();
            br.close();

            String[] key = line.split(" ");
            HuffmanNode[] huffs = new HuffmanNode[ key.length / 2];
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            while( i < key.length )
            {
                huffs[ j ] = new HuffmanNode( key[i], key[i + 1]);
//          System.out.println( key[i] + " " + key[i + 1 ] );

                i = i + 2;
                j++;
            }

            BinaryHeap heap = new BinaryHeap( huffs );
            return heap;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static HuffmanTree createFromHeap(BinaryHeap b)
    {
        try {
            while( b.getSize() > 1 )
            {
                HuffmanNode huff1 = (HuffmanNode) b.deleteMin();
                HuffmanNode huff2 = (HuffmanNode) b.deleteMin();
                HuffmanNode huff = new HuffmanNode( huff1, huff2 );
                b.insert( huff );
            }
            HuffmanTree tree = new HuffmanTree( (HuffmanNode) b.deleteMin() );
            return tree;
        } catch (Underflow e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // - the main method will go here, as well as code to take
    //   a command-line argument for the input file name
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        **// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BinaryHeap bheap = HuffmanTree.fileToHeap( "EE.txt");

        bheap.printHeap();
        HuffmanTree htree = HuffmanTree.createFromHeap( bheap );
        htree.printLegend();
    }**

}
```

I believe it is the main method that is causing all of the problems. I just am not quite sure how to edit it.

Compiler:

```
HuffmanEncoder % java HuffmanTree EE.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "R"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:735)
    at HuffmanNode.<init>(HuffmanNode.java:16)
    at HuffmanTree.fileToHeap(HuffmanTree.java:53)
    at HuffmanTree.main(HuffmanTree.java:99)
```